# Animating a div sliding into a container

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I have code I have posted on the following fiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/eE2Xn/2/

It's basic intent is upon clicking the button, to slide the red div down over the gray one to become the first child of `#container`.

The other children of `#container` should make room for the red box. And another red box (hopefully with the same bindings, hence the deep cloning) should appear in its stead.

It seems to sort of be there (my actual code seems a bit better than this generalized fiddle version), but the animation spazzes out a lot, and I can't figure it out.

How do I achieve this effect? I'm using jQuery and jQuery UI edge in both.

Comment: So I'm assuming once the red box in `#container`, it loses its bindings?

Comment: In my own code, the red box contains other elements that have bindings that are then `.empty()`'d, so yes. There are no direct bindings to the red box.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have everything within a callback function or `.delay()` it before the next one is done.

Callback functions work like:

```
$('#thing').fadeIn('3000', function () {
    // Have your next animation here
});
```

For info on `.delay()`, read more here: http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: Could you elaborate? The two animations are simultaneous, because I want the green boxes to make room for the red one as it's moving down.